# Restrictive access to fields in workitem

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

I am working on customizing TFS workitem template for quite a while. But I am not able to find anyway in which you can **restrict** particular field in template - say "**Priority**" - depending on user. I mean I have TFS users A,B,C and D and I have requirement like - **Priority** field should be changeable only by A and B. I tried using **VALIDUSER** rule on Priority field but failed to succeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use a [`READONLY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404861.aspx) field with a `for` \ `notfor` specified.

Example:

```
<READONLY for="DevelopmentUserGroup" notfor="AdminUserGroup" />
```